# Python: Find the longest word in a string

Tags: python, string

I'm preparing for an exam but I'm having difficulties with one past-paper question. Given a string containing a sentence, I want to find the longest word in that sentence and return that word and its length. **Edit:** I only needed to return the length but I appreciate your answers for the original question! It helps me learn more. Thank you.

For example: string = "Hello I like cookies". My program should then return "Cookies" and the length 7.

Now the thing is that I am not allowed to use any function from the class String for a full score, and for a full score I can only go through the string once. I am not allowed to use string.split() (otherwise there wouldn't be any problem) and the solution shouldn't have too many for and while statements. The strings contains only letters and blanks and words are separated by one single blank.

Any suggestions? I'm lost i.e. I don't have any code.

Thanks.

**EDIT**: I'm sorry, I misread the exam question. You only have to return the length of the longest word it seems, not the length + the word.

**EDIT2**: Okay, with your help I think I'm onto something...

```
def longestword(x):
      alist = []
      length = 0
      for letter in x:
             if letter != " ":
                     length += 1
             else:
                     alist.append(length)
                     length = 0
      return alist
```

But it returns [5, 1, 4] for "Hello I like cookies" so it misses "cookies". Why? EDIT: Ok, I got it. It's because there's no more " " after the last letter in the sentence and therefore it doesn't append the length. I fixed it so now it returns [5, 1, 4, 7] and then I just take the maximum value.

I suppose using lists but not .split() is okay? It just said that functions from "String" weren't allowed or are lists part of strings?

Comment: Technically, you can import the string module and call split from there because you wouldn't be using it from the string class. Maybe this is a test of knowing the documentation.

Comment: If you test only that the letter is not `" "`, it will fail with punctuation: `Hello, I like cookies!"`. You'd better test that the character is not a letter.

Comment: @FrancisColas my bad again. It says in the exam question that "The text contains only letters and blanks, and each word is separated by one single blank". Then it's fine?

Comment: Yes, in that case it works fine: your test is also faster than mine and simpler than using regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding a max in one pass is easy:

```
current_max = 0
for v in values:
    if v>current_max:
        current_max = v
```

But in your case, you need to find the words. Remember this quote (attribute to J. Zawinski):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Besides using regular expressions, you can simply check that the word has letters. A first approach is to go through the list and detect start or end of words:

```
current_word = ''
current_longest = ''
for c in mystring:
    if c in string.ascii_letters:
        current_word += c
    else:
        if len(current_word)>len(current_longest):
            current_longest = current_word
            current_word = ''
else:
    if len(current_word)>len(current_longest):
        current_longest = current_word
```

A final way is to split words in a generator and find the max of what it yields (here I used the `max` function):

```
def split_words(mystring):
    current = []
    for c in mystring:
        if c in string.ascii_letters:
            current.append(c)
        else:
            if current:
                yield ''.join(current)
max(split_words(mystring), key=len)
```

Comment: That first method fails to detect "cookies" because it's the last word in the string.

Comment: Indeed (I had read `"I like cookies."` with punctuation). I edited with a fix.

Comment: I like the generator/max approach, it is elegant and modular. Not sure this is the intended approach for the exercise, but it would deserve full score imo. You would have to tweak it a bit so the word is returned as well, though.

Comment: Thank you, very thorough answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use regular expressions:

```
import re

string = "Hello I like cookies"
word_pattern = "\w+"

regex = re.compile(word_pattern)
words_found = regex.findall(string)

if words_found:
    longest_word = max(words_found, key=lambda word: len(word))
    print(longest_word)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at this some more. We haven't talked about regular expressions I think.

Answer (score 2):

Just search for groups of non-whitespace characters, then find the maximum by length:

```
longest = len(max(re.findall(r'\S+',string), key = len))
```

Comment: The OP stated that using `split` is not allowed.

Comment: Okay, I'll just use regex then.

Comment: This returns the longest words length, not the actual word.

Comment: @ChaseRoberts Ok no problem, remove the call to `len`

Answer (score 2):

For python 3. If both the words in the sentence is of the same length, then it will return the word that appears first.

```
def findMaximum(word):
    li=word.split()
    li=list(li)
    op=[]
    for i in li:
        op.append(len(i))
    l=op.index(max(op))
    print (li[l])
findMaximum(input("Enter your word:"))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple:

```
def long_word(s):
    n = max(s.split())
    return(n)
```

**IN [48]:** `long_word('a bb ccc dddd')`

**Out[48]:** `'dddd'`

Comment: This is not the questions' answer, it returns the highest word by alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1):

found an error in a previous provided solution, he's the correction:

```
def longestWord(text):
    
    current_word = ''
    current_longest = ''
    for c in text:
        if c in string.ascii_letters:
            current_word += c
        else:
            if len(current_word)>len(current_longest):
                current_longest = current_word
            current_word = ''    

    if len(current_word)>len(current_longest):
        current_longest = current_word
    return   current_longest
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see imagine some different alternatives. [Regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) can probably do much of the splitting words you need to do. This could be a simple option if you understand regexes.

An alternative is to treat the string as a list, iterate over it keeping track of your index, and looking at each character to see if you're ending a word. Then you just need to keep the longest word (longest index difference) and you should find your answer.

Comment: Thanks, your second paragraph inspired me and I *think* I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expressions seems to be your best bet. First use `re` to split the sentence:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "Hello I like cookies"
>>> string = re.findall(r'\S+',string)
```

`\S+` looks for all the non-whitespace characters and puts them in a list:

```
>>> string
['Hello', 'I', 'like', 'cookies']
```

Now you can find the length of the list element containing the longest word and then use list comprehension to retrieve the element itself:

```
>>> maxlen = max(len(word) for word in string)
>>> maxlen
7
>>> [word for word in string if len(word) == maxlen]
['cookies']
```

Answer (score 0):

This method uses only one `for` loop, doesn't use any methods in the `String` class, strictly accesses each character only once.  You may have to modify it depending on what characters count as part of a word.

```
s = "Hello I like cookies"
word = ''
maxLen = 0
maxWord = ''
for c in s+' ':
    if c == ' ':
        if len(word) > maxLen:
            maxWord = word
        word = ''
    else:
        word += c


print "Longest word:", maxWord
print "Length:", len(maxWord)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you are not allowed to use `string.split()` I guess using a regexp to do the exact same thing should be ruled out as well.

I do not want to solve your exercise for you, but here are a few pointers:

- Suppose you have a list of numbers and you want to return the highest value. How would you do that? What information do you need to track?
- Now, given your string, how would you build a list of all word lengths? What do you need to keep track of?
- Now, you only have to intertwine both logics so computed word lengths are compared as you go through the string.

Answer (score 0):

## My proposal ...

```
import re
def longer_word(sentence):
    word_list = re.findall("\w+", sentence)
    word_list.sort(cmp=lambda a,b: cmp(len(b),len(a)))
    longer_word = word_list[0]
    print "The longer word is '"+longer_word+"' with a size of", len(longer_word), "characters."
longer_word("Hello I like cookies")
```

Comment: Mmt, Regarding your code, you cannot find cookies, because there is no space at the end of your string .. and the the last word is never stored in your list.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

def longest_word(sen):
  res = re.findall(r"\w+",sen)
  n = max(res,key = lambda x : len(x))
  return n

print(longest_word("Hey!! there, How is it going????"))
```

**Output** : **there**

Here I have used `regex` for the problem. Variable **"res"** finds all the words in the string and itself stores them in the list after splitting them.
It uses `split()` to store all the characters in a list and then `regex` does the work.

`findall` keyword is used to find all the desired instances in a string. Here `\w+` is defined which tells the compiler to look for all the **words** without any spaces.

Variable **"n"** finds the longest word from the given string which is now free of any undesired characters.

Variable **"n"** uses `lambda expressions` to  define the key `len()` here.

Variable **"n"** finds the longest word from "res" which has removed all the non-string charcters like %,&,! etc.

```
>>>#import regular expressions for the problem.**
>>>import re

>>>#initialize a sentence
>>>sen = "fun&!! time zone"

>>>res = re.findall(r"\w+",sen)
>>>#res variable finds all the words and then stores them in a list.

>>>res
Out: ['fun','time','zone']

>>>n = max(res)
Out: zone

>>>#Here we get "zone" instead of "time" because here the compiler
>>>#sees "zone" with the higher value than "time".
>>>#The max() function returns the item with the highest value, or the item with the highest value in an iterable.

>>>n = max(res,key = lambda x:len(x))
>>>n
Out: time
```

Here we get **"time"** because lambda expression discards **"zone"** as it sees the key is for `len()` in a `max()` function.

Answer (score 0):

in case you want to ignore punctuation as well here is a more Pythonic way: this will return the longest string you can use len to get length and return it

```
from string import punctuation
def longest_word(str):
   return max("".join([s for s in str if s not in punctuation]).split(" "), key=len)
```

in case you have two strings with the same length the first one that appeared will be returned

**simple Inputs,Outputs:**

```
print(longest_word("test1 test2")) # -> test1
print(longest_word("t.est1: test2")) # -> test1
print(longest_word("hy: hello")) # -> hello
```

Answer (score -1):

```
list1 = ['Happy', 'Independence', 'Day', 'Zeal']
listLen = []
for i in list1:
          listLen.append(len(i))
print list1[listLen.index(max(listLen))]
```

Output - Independence