# How to find the longest word in a string without using split method

Tags: python

I need an algorithm that can find the longest word in a string, I can't use `split()`, the only predefined function I can use is `find()` and I don't think it's useful for this solution.

This is what I managed to do so far:

```
ch=input("donner: ")

def plus_long(ch):
    p=ch.find(" ")
    if p==-1:
        return ch
    maximum=""
    mot=""
    while p!=-1:
        mot=ch[:p]
        print(mot)
        ch=ch[p+1:]
        print(ch)
        if len(mot)>len(maximum):
            maximum=mot
        p=ch.find(" ")
        
    return maximum

print("maximum est: ",plus_long(ch))
```

But this one doesn't check the last word because there are no more spaces.

EDIT: Thank you all for the answers, i realised how to solve it this morning by putting ch in a new variable and comparing it to maximum and it worked

```
   ch=input("donner: ")
def plus_long(ch):
    p=ch.find(" ")
    if p==-1:
        return ch
    maximum=""
    mot=""
    while p!=-1:
        mot=ch[:p]
        print(mot)
        ch=ch[p+1:len(ch)]
        print(ch)
        if len(mot)>len(maximum):
            maximum=mot
        p=ch.find(" ")
    f=ch
    if len(f)>len(maximum):
        maximum=f
    return maximum
print("maximum est: ",plus_long(ch))
```

Comment: 1. Don't call variables in French. 2. Why can't you use split?

Comment: Sorry about the french variables, and teacher told us not to use split 

Comment: Then use `ch.replace(' ', '\n').splitlines()` :-P

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Find the longest word in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982305/python-find-the-longest-word-in-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've split this problem into two parts:

1. Use `find` to create the list of words.
2. Find the longest word in the list.

```
def plus_long(ch):

    letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    words = ['']
    for v in ch:
        if letters.find(v.lower()) != -1: # Use find to check if the character is part of the alphabet
            words[-1] += v # If so, add that character to the last string in the list
        else:
            words.append('') # Else, start a new string

    result = "" # Check which string is the longest
    for word in words:
        if len(word) > len(result):
            result = word

    return result
```

Test:

```
>>> plus_long("Hello!!!!!!!!!!! How are you? I am exhausted.")
```

Output:

```
'exhausted'
```

---

*I see that the other answers don't put punctuation into account, so that using their functions, the result would be `'Hello!!!!!!!!!!!'`.*

Answer (score 1):

You can find using `split` and `len`:

```
# Longest word

# Reading sentence from user

sentence = input("Enter sentence: ")

# Finding longest word
longest = max(sentence.split(), key=len)

# Displaying longest word
print("Longest word is: ", longest)
print("And its length is: ", len(longest))
```

The output is:

```
Enter sentence: Tongue tied and twisted just an earth bound misfit I
Longest word is:  twisted
And its length is:  7
```

Comment: OP says `i can't use split()`. My guess is this is homework.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code with an addition that checks the last word (len) when `p == -1` just as the loop is going to exit. This addition reported the correct max length if the last word is greater than maximum.

```
ch=input("donner: ")

def plus_long(ch):
    p=ch.find(" ")
    if p==-1:
        return ch
    maximum=""
    mot=""
    while p!=-1:
        mot=ch[:p]
        print(mot)
        ch=ch[p+1:]
        print(ch)
        if len(mot)>len(maximum):
            maximum=mot
        p=ch.find(" ")

        # 'ch' now has the last word in a sentence
        # it needs to be checked against 'maximum'
        if p == -1:
            if len(ch) > len(maximum):
                maximum = ch
            
        
    return maximum

print("maximum est: ",plus_long(ch))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
ch=input("donner: ")

def plus_long(ch):
    word = ''
    maximum = ''
    for letter in ch:
        if letter == ' ':
            if len(maximum) < len(word):
                maximum = word
            word = ''
        else:
            word += letter
        
    return maximum


print("maximum est: ",plus_long(ch))
```

Comment: This does not return the word of maximum length, and it does not solve the OP's problem of not returning the last word if it's the longest.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `p` to `None` if the `find` method returns `-1` so that `ch[:p]` would slice the rest of the string to get the last word:

```
def plus_long(ch):
    maximum = ""
    while True:
        p = ch.find(" ")
        if p == -1:
            p = None
        mot = ch[:p]
        if len(mot) > len(maximum):
            maximum = mot
        if p is None:
            break
        ch = ch[p + 1:]
    return maximum
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `find`

```
def plus_long(ch):
  longest = ""
  i = 0
  while i < len(ch):
    n = ch.find(" ", i)
    if n == -1:
      n = len(ch)

    if len(longest) < len(ch[i:n]):
      longest = ch[i:n]

    i = n+1
```

Test:

```
print (plus_long("there is a cat on a very big banana tree"))
print (plus_long("there is a cat on a mountain"))
print (plus_long("there"))
```

Output:

```
banana
mountain
there
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a very long and probably the worst method as far as Big 'O' Notation is concerned but it is a simple approach for beginners.

```
def longWord (sentence):
    singleWord = ""
    words = []
    for letter in sentence:
        
        if letter != " ":
            singleWord += letter
        else:
            words += [singleWord]
            singleWord = ""
    words += [singleWord]
    
    for i in range(len(words)-1):
        biggestWord = ""
        if len(words[i]) >= len(words[i+1]):
            biggestWord += words[i]
            
        else:
            biggestWord += words[i+1]
    
    print(words)
    print(biggestWord)
    
longWord("This is a callback")
```

OUTPUT -

```
['This', 'is', 'a', 'callback']
callback
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you already have a few answers. Here's a code with O(1)

```
ch=input("donner: ")
prev_pos = 0
max_word = ''
for i, sp in enumerate(ch):
    if sp == ' ':
        if len(ch[prev_pos:i]) > len(max_word): max_word = ch[prev_pos:i]
        prev_pos = i+1
if len(ch[prev_pos:]) > len(max_word): max_word = ch[prev_pos:]
print ('longest word :', max_word, 'length :', len(max_word))
```

The output for this are:

```
donner: sentence
longest word : sentence length : 8

donner: this sentence
longest word : sentence length : 8

donner: this is a sentence
longest word : sentence length : 8

donner: this sentence is expectedly very lengthy
longest word : expectedly length : 10

donner: word is lengthy
longest word : lengthy length : 7
```

I wanted to give you an alternate approach as well. I have added comments for you to understand the code

```
ch=input("donner: ")             #input the sentence
word = ''                        #capture each word in this variable
wd = []                          #store all the words into this list
for sp in ch:                    #iterate thru the string
    if sp != ' ': word += sp     #concat to create the word
    else:
        wd.append(word)          #add the word to list
        word = ''                #reset word
wd.append(word)                  #add the last word to the list
long_word = max(wd,key=len)      #find the longest word
print ('longest word :',long_word, 'length :', len(long_word))
```